# How to get post which have multiple table relationship?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, many-to-many, relationship

my database scheema

**Table POST**

```
| id | title | content |
```

**Table SharedGroup**

```
|id | title | slug
```

**Table  Post_SharedGroup**

```
|id| post_id | shared_group_id|
```

i want to make a query in laravel that i give slug of sharedgroup and get post of it

Comment: Please add sample input data along with the expected output.

Comment: i have slug sharedgroup and i want its related posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$data = Post::whereHas('sharedGroup',function($query) use($slug){
        $query->whereIn('slug',$slug);
       })->get();
```

where `$slug` is your slug array given by you

Model Post

```
public function sharedGroup(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\SharedGroup');
}
```

Model SharedGroup

```
public function post(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
}
```

Comment: i will give multiple slugs not only one and i want to return Posts

Comment: user `whereIn()` instead of `where()`... I  updated answer

Comment: i want return Post Model instead of SharedGroup

Answer (score 0):

You seem to just want a basic join between the three tables:

```
$posts = DB::table('POST p')
    ->join('Post_SharedGroup ps', 'p.id', '=', 'ps.post_id')
    ->join('SharedGroup s', 'ps.shared_group_id', '=', 's.id')
    ->whereIn('s.slug', array(1, 2, 3))  // match slug values (1, 2, 3)
    ->select('p.*')
    ->get();
```

Comment: i want to give multiple sharedgroup slugs

Comment: @RevTech Then use Laravel's `whereIn()` function, and pass in an array of matching `slug` values.

Comment: is it possible without join ?

Comment: Note that I know of...maybe the framework has a way of hiding the join, but a join would certainly be happening under the hood on your MySQL database.